# Whether performance will impact when database procedure is called from application many times?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oracle, performance, oracle-pro-c

In my project, we are calling the oracle procedure from our c++ application with 
the help of Pro *C/C++ library provided by the oracle.

We have one big procedure, and my idea is to split the procedure in to two for modularity. But their advice is to call the procedure for one time, and perform all jobs at a shot.

The reason which i got from them is it will cause performance impacts, since application program is interacting with database for multiple times.

I agree, the above scenario will happen when application connects the database, calls the procedure and finally disconnects the database for each procedure call. But, what we really do is we create a pool of connections at startup, and reuse that pre-connected database connections for interacting with the database.

**Information about my application:**

1. It is `multi-threaded application`, which handles about 1000 request per second with thread pool size as 20. Currently for each request we communicate with database for 4 times.

**EDIT:**

"the switch between PLSQL and SQL is much faster than the other way around". 
Q1. How this is is related to my actual question? My question is about spiliting a procedure in to two equal parts. Say suppose i have 4 queries executed in procedure, i just split it in to two as procedure a and procedure b, and each procedure will have two queries.

"pro*c calls which call PLSQL is an performance hit". 
Q2. Do you mean an communication between application(pro *C/C++) and database(oracle) here? If so, is communication was a big performance hit?

In the ask tom link you have attached, "But don't be afraid at all to invoke SQL from PLSQL - that is what PLSQL does best"
Q4. Wheather context switch will happen while we call SQL from PLSQL? Because, as per above statement, it seems to be no performanace impact.

Comment: Have you measured it to see what the real world impact is?

Answer (score 1):

Your advice is correct, it would be better to perform all database tasks at once. There are 2 major performance impacts in your scenario

1. The context switching of pro*c between the SQL engine and the PL/SQL engine to run your threads multiple times. Usually the biggest issue in many PL/SQL calls from a client application.
2. The network stack overhead (TNS) in the communications between your pro*c app and the database engine - particularly if your app is on a different physical host.

Having said that, you are creating a connection pool at the application end the TNS listener should also have a pool of bequeathed server shadow processes waiting for each network connection (this is setup at the listener.ora).

The OCI login/logoff when the shadow process is already waiting for connect is very quick and not a huge factor in latency - I don't worry about this unless a new shadow process on the server has to start up - then it can be a very expensive call. As you are using connection pooling on the client side, this is usually not an issue but just something to consider because of the threading in your calls. Once you exhaust the pool of server shadow processes, you will notice a huge degradation if the TNS listener has to start up more server shadow process.

**Edit in answer to the new questions:**

1. It is very related. As pointed out previously, you should minimise the amount of plsql and sql calls within your C++ app. Each PLSQL call within your C++ app call invokes the SQL engine which then invokes the PLSQL engine for the procedure call. So if you split your procedure into 2 - you are doubling the SQL to PLSQL context switches which is the more expensive switch as outlined by the Tom Kyte article and my own personal experience.
2. Is answered in 1. But as I previously said the communications overhead is second unless your hosts are on different physical networks and the types of data you are transferring. For instance large C++ object parameters and large Oracle result sets with many calls will obviously affect communications latency with round trips. Remember that with more PLSQL calls you are also adding more SQLNET traffic for the setup for each connection and result set.
3. there is no 3. question
4. PLSQL to SQL within the PLSQL engine is negligible so don't get hung up on it. Put all your SQL calls within 1 PLSQL call for maximum performance throughput. Don't split the calls just to be more eloquent at the expensive of performance.

Comment: i have understood that, plsql engine is different and sql engine is different.  since two engines are different, it will take time for context switching. Consider i am spliting my procedure in to two equal parts. As per my undestanding context switch will happen for each sql query in the procedure.
So, even we split the procedure context switching will happen for same number of times. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You are almost correct - the switch between PLSQL and SQL is much faster than the other way around. So having a few SQL calls within your 1 or 2 PLSQL calls I wouldn't worry too much about. However, having many pro*c calls which call SQL, then a PLSQL routine and so forth - which I have seen many times is a big performance hit. More information here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:60122715103602

Comment: Please see the new edit. I believe with the ask tom article this should answer your question and it would be appreciated if you mark it so.

Comment: @ Rob Mascaro Thank you so much for your patience.. I have understood now. I thought like C++ application will directly call the PL/SQL engine. I understood now that it will call SQL engine, which inturn calls the PL/SQL engine. But i am curious to now why it is called so?

Posted another question related this too..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402262/why-sql-engine-is-called-for-pl-sql-call-from-client-application